# Find a file by hash

Tags: command-line, find, hashsum

I have a file x1 in one directory (d1) and I'm not sure if the same
file is already copied (x2) in another directory (d2) (but automatically
renamed by application).

Can I check if hash of file x1 from directory d1 is equal to hash of some file x2 existing in directory d2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good approach, but the search will be a lot faster if you only calculate hashes of files that have the right size. Using GNU/BusyBox utilities:

```
wanted_size=$(stat -c %s d1/x1)
wanted_hash=$(sha256sum <d1/x1)
find d2 -type f -size "${wanted_size}c" -execdir sh -c 'test "$(sha256sum <"$0")" = "$1"' {} "$wanted_hash" \; -print
```

Answer (score 1):

To find a file with a known MD5 digest in a directory (using `bash` or `ksh93`):

```
x1digest="$( md5sum d1/x1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1 )"

for x2 in d2/*; do
    if [[ ! -f "$fpath" ]]; then
      continue
    fi

    x2digest="$( md5sum "$fpath" | cut -d ' ' -f 1 )"

    if [[ "$x2digest" == "$x1digest" ]]; then
      printf '"%s" has the same hash as d1/x1\n' "$fpath"
    fi
done
```

On BSD systems, `md5sum filename | cut -d ' ' -f 1` can be replaced by `md5 -q filename`.